# TypeScript: how to send array as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am sending an array of data to a component as a prop, like:

```
<InfoTable TableInfo={tableRows} />;
```

Where `tableRows` is the array.

On my InfoTable component file I define my props like

```
interface InfoTableProps {
  tableInfo: TableInfo[];
}
```

Which allows me to `.map()` through the tableInfo array, eg:

```
let tableRow = tableInfo.map(function(tableInfoRow) {
  // Do some stuff
}
```

This works fine. However, my compiler gets a warning on `tableInfo: TableInfo[];`

> Cannot find name 'TableInfo'.  TS2304

I've tried Googling the problem of course but I just get people asking the same question.

Would anyone know how to remove this error or what it means?

Comment: And it looks like you've named the prop as `tableInfo` but you're passing `TableInfo={}`, so maybe it's just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to define the `TableInfo` type somewhere?

eg

```
Interface TableInfo {
  id: number
  name: string
}
```

Sorry If you've already done that and its something else :-)

Comment: So I need to declare each key in the array as well?

Comment: yes. rn typescript doesn't know the structure of each item in your array. When you write `TableInfo[]`, you're saying "an array of TableInfo-shaped things". Typescript wants to know what each of those things looks like.

Comment: that'll be due to the typo that Emile mentioned above :)